# How to fix CKeditor not having upload image feature in laravel project

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

My ckeditor does not have an upload image feature. I'd like the feature to be available. How does one work around that in laravel?

Comment: Ckeditor4 or 5? Post your js code also.

Comment: <!-- CK Editor -->
      
` <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/full/ckeditor.js"></script> `
    



`<script> 
        $(function () { CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        $('.textarea').wysihtml5(); });
 </script> `

Comment: @TalhaF. I've provided the  requested info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CKFinder` that enables uploading and managing multiple files easily. With the built-in image editor cropping, resizing, rotating, adjusting brightness, contrast, saturation, exposure, and sharpness plus some pre-defined filter presets are available.

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files'
    } );

    $('.textarea').wysihtml5();

</script>
```

Documentation [Here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/demo/ckfinder3/samples/ckeditor.html)

For laravel :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{ route('ckeditor.upload', ['_token' => csrf_token() ])}}",
    filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
});
```

In your route :

```
Route::post('images/upload', 'ImageController@upload')->name('ckeditor.upload');
```

And your `ImageController` :

```
public function upload(Request $request)
 {
     if($request->hasFile('upload')) {
         $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
         $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
         $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $fileName = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        
         $request->file('upload')->move(public_path('images'), $fileName);
   
         $CKEditorFuncNum = $request->input('CKEditorFuncNum');
         $url = asset('images/'.$fileName); 
         $msg = 'Image uploaded successfully'; 
         $response = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url', '$msg')</script>";
               
         @header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
         echo $response;
     }
}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: I tried and the uploading Image feature is now available. Just one clarification, do I need to send it to the server first so as to upload an image?

Comment: @Alphy yes, you need to send it to the server first.

Comment: is there any advantage of the second approach over the first one? I find the first second approach verbose. In your experience which approach would you recommend between the two?

Comment: The first approach is for normal js (raw php, python etc). And the second approach is just for Laravel. If you  understand the first approach then you need  you add route, controller. So in second approach I added it all. So Both are same approach :)