# CKFinder Integration : cors issue & unexpected end of json input

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ckeditor, ckfinder

1. I am trying to using vue.js connect to CKFinder which I was built in
   Laravel ( work fine when in Laravel ) but it faces the problem when
   use vue.js call the CKFinder
2. I was trying to use the script  to
   make the integration but it still facing the problem below
3. I have tested to call API from Laravel it works fine and doesn't
   have any issue of CORS, but when connecting to CKFinder it fails...

Issue Image
[image: ![image]

Follow was my Configuration CKFinder Vue.JS Code
The added script in index.html page

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.2:8000/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

Follow code is the configuration in my editor page

```
      ckfinder: {
          // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
          uploadUrl:'http://127.0.0.2:8000/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json',

          // Define the CKFinder configuration (if necessary).
          options: {
              resourceType: 'Images'
          },

          openerMethod: 'popup'
      },
```

Comment: This is vue.js issue, but if this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62484365/how-to-fix-ckeditor-not-having-upload-image-feature-in-laravel-project/62485424#62485424

Comment: thanks for your suggestion is good to know about this method.
I am looking for the integration from VUE to Laravel. If I don't insert that JS it will show popup not found error. But when I inserted the JS show the cors issue