# How to set up CKEditor 5 in Vuetify to upload image with Laravel Sanctum credentials

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I use CKEditor in a Vuetify application. I like to upload the images to the server. But i do not find any way to upload themes with credentials.

Does someone has an idea how to set up the ckfinder? I tried many things, but no success.

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/62485424/4575350

Comment: And how can i send the credentials for Sanctum auth with?

Answer (score 0):

**you can use simpleupload**

```
<ckeditor-nuxt :config="editorConfig" v-model="form_content" />
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
   
      form_content: "",
   
    };
  },
    components: {
      "ckeditor-nuxt": () => import(".... ");
    }
     async created() {
          this.editorConfig = {
                 simpleUpload: {
        
                }
           }
        
     }
}
</script>
```